# How to find out if glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE) is working for my texture?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, multisampling

I am trying to display an image in full window using two simple GLSL shaders:

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
    TexCoord = aTexCoord;
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

and fragment shader:

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2D tex0; // loading the texture here

in vec3 TexCoord; // texture coordinates
out vec4 fColor; // fragment shader output

void main(){
   fColor = texture2D(tex0,TexCoord);
}
```

In the OpenGL code, during OpenGL properties setting, I perform

```
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
```

**I read online that the OpenGL will ONLY perform Multisampling if the drivers support this.**

Is there anyway in OpenGL we can confirm that the above call is working ? 
Or is there anyway we can find out if my machine graphics card supports this call ?

Comment: I wouldn't be aware that this depends on the driver capabilities. It definitely depends on whether your render target supports multisampling, but that's not directly related to the driver.

Comment: I was checking some example codes to perform this and I came across this file: 

[example code](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer.php?code=advanced/anti_aliasing_multisampling)

In this search for **glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)** .

There is a comment mentioning its driver based.

Is there a way to confirm if the render target supports Multisampling ?

Comment: From a first view, I see nothing that states something similar than your bold text in your link. The only note I see is about whether multi-sampling is enabled by default or not. If your windowing system can give you a multisampled window/backbuffer and a OpenGL context > 1.3 then multisampling has to work.

Comment: Having multisampling enabled or not does not relate to whether multisampling is supported or not. It just specifies if multisampling should be used or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the general case, seeing if your implementation supports multisampling is easy.

You can get multisampling in two ways: a multisampled default framebuffer, or a multisampled FBO. The latter can only happen by you *explicitly* creating multisampled images for your FBO. I think you can tell when you're calling `glRenderbufferStorageMultisample` or `glTexStorage2DMultisample`, but that doesn't matter, because you can ask any framebuffer (FBO or default) if it has multiple samples.

To do that, you can bind the framebuffer to the `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER` and call `glGetIntegerv` with `GL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS`. If that value is 1, then the buffer is mulitsampled. You can get the number of samples by querying `GL_SAMPLES`.

Note that GL 4.5 and above allow you to use `glGet(Named)FramebufferParameteriv` to query these parameters, so that you don't have to bind the FBO.

---

All that being said, you have one big problem. Nothing you've done in your rendering will be multisampled. Multisampling *cannot* anti-alias a textured quad. It only performs anti-aliasing at the edges of *triangles*. Unless you turn on per-sample shading (which you shouldn't unless you don't like performance), data fetched from texels will not be affected.

So even if multisampling is going on, your *specific* rendering operation will not see the effects of it.